# Question about Objects and Pointers in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>

struct Human {
public:
    std::string Name; 
    int* Age;
    Human(std::string Name, int Age): Name{Name}, Age{&Age} {}
    void Print() {
        std::cout << Name << " " << Age << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Human a = Human("John", 35);
    Human b = Human("Brook", 20);
    Human c = Human("Lamy", 90);
    Human d = Human("Ed", 5);
    a.Print();
    b.Print();
    c.Print();
    d.Print();
}

/* Output
John 0x7bfc80
Brook 0x7bfc80
Lamy 0x7bfc80
Ed 0x7bfc80
*/
```

How come all the age value addresses are the same in the ouput? How am I able to send a constant value into something that will take its address? (check parameterized constructor) A constant has no well defined position in memory so how is that acceptable? Is the variable int* Age not being duplicated for each object creation?

Thank you!

Comment: Code would Undefined Behaviour if it dereference `Age` _"...warning: initializing pointer member 'Age' with the stack address of parameter 'Age' [-Wdangling-field].."_ live - https://godbolt.org/z/z4fYK6hGT  if possible set the compiler warning level to catch this.

Comment: You keep invalid addresses of local variables.

Comment: @RichardCritten is it UB? `Age` is never dereferenced

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number you are right - updated comment.

Comment: The real question has to be why. Why would you want to make `Age` a pointer? I appreciate you might just be experimenting, but I often get the sense the newbies think that pointers are better, in some mysterious way, and use them when they are inappropriate.

Comment: The address you are taking is not the address of the constant (which doesn't make sense as you say), but the address of the `Age` parameter to your constructor.

Comment: @john I was just testing it out because I already experimented with dynamic pointers in class/struct but not regular ones.

Comment: @john So a duplicate of the Age pointer is not made for each object creation? It's jus the same one being passed around for each object that is made?

Comment: @imheretolearn It's hard to explain because you use the same name for two different things. The `int Age`, which is passed as constructor parameter, only lives as long as the constructor is running. Once constructor finishes, `int Age` is destroyed and its memory released for later use. By accident, next constructor call places its own `int Age` in the same memory area, so getting an address of that results in the same value of pointer.

Comment: @imheretolearn Yes, a duplicate of the pointer is made, but each duplicate has the same value. Which is why they print the same.

Comment: @imheretolearn There are no differences between dynamic pointers and regular pointers, they're all just pointers. There are differences between dynamically allocated objects and regular objects however (the difference being in the lifetimes of those objects).

Answer (score 5):

The addresses are those of the constructor argument. Your constructor is

```
Human(std::string Name, int Age): Name{Name}, Age{&Age} {}
```

That means: `Name` and `Age` are passed by value, a copy of the parameters is made. You then store the adress of this argument in the member. This doesnt make much sense. `Age` is local to the constuctor. Its lifetime ends when the constructor returns. What you store in the member is a dangling pointer. This is an example of pointless use of pointers. Make the `Age` member an `int`.

Note that if you would print the value the member is pointing to `std::cout << *Age;` in the `Print` method, your program would invoke undefined behavior, because the `int` to which the pointer points has its lifetime ended when the constructor returns.

Comment: So every argument in a function (constructor or not) has its own address in memory?

Comment: @imheretolearn Every object has an address, but the addresses are not necessarily unique. Once an object has been destroyed, the same address maybe reused for another object.

Comment: @imheretolearn Every time a constructor or function is called, all of it's parameters (that are objects) get created and given an address. So in your case the `Age` parameter is created four times, and (it just so happens) given the same address each time. But it doesn't have to be that way, it's just how your compiler happened to compile your program.

Comment: @john i think i understand it now, so basically every function parameter has its own place in memory. so when i created those objects with a constant it sent a copy to that parameter but when i made its address equal to the data member Age it took the address of the constructor argument. also at the end of every constructor/function call it ends which removes it off the runtime stack. then it just so happens that that location is reused, hence why i got the same addresses

Comment: @imheretolearn Yep, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a tiny mistake in your code. The two line:

```
    int* Age;
    Human(std::string Name, int Age): Name{Name}, Age{&Age} {}
```

has to be changed to:

```
    int Age;
    Human(std::string Name, int Age): Name{Name}, Age{Age} {}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).